# When I request a request, it returns 401 unauthorized for each request in the security section

Tags: java, spring, api, security, boot

I am making a project for Register and Login operations. I am using spring security and jwt. It always returns 401 unauthorized to any request I throw in Postman. I couldn't find the reason. Could you help? I am using spring boot new version. 3.0.0 version.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

  private final AuthenticationService service;

  @PostMapping("/register")
  public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(
      @RequestBody RegisterRequest request
  ) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.register(request));
  }
  @PostMapping("/authenticate")
  public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
      @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
  ) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.authenticate(request));
  }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final JwtService jwtService;
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
      @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
      @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String jwt;
    final String userEmail;
    if (authHeader == null ||!authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }
    jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
    userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
    if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
      if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails,
            null,
            userDetails.getAuthorities()
        );
        authToken.setDetails(
            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
        );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

  private final CustomerRepository repository;

  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return username -> repository.findByEmail(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
    return config.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

}
```

I want to register and then login. I want to access some controllers based on role.